# JSのオブジェクトの直前プロパティを使いたい

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
  a: 2,
  b: 5,
  c: obj.a + obj.b
};
```

このような感じで `c` に前で宣言したプロパティを利用したいときどのように記述すればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

回答ありがとうございます。yyzさんの回答をヒントに調べて見るといい方法がありました。

```
var obj = {
    a: 2,
    b: 5,
    get c() {
        return this.a + this.b;
    }
};
obj.c;  // 7
```

IE9以上なら `get` 演算子で簡単に書けるみたいです。

Comment: `obj`を代入後、`a`か`b`を変えると`c`も変わってしまいますが、それは期待通りなのでしょうか

Comment: 今回の場合はその動作で問題ないのですが、もし他に方法があれば教えて欲しいです。

Comment: プロパティcが動的に変更されないなら、@emix さんの回答になるのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

普通に代入じゃダメ？

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = 2;
obj.b = 5;
obj.c = obj.a + obj.b;
```

Answer (score 1):

obj.c　が関数になってしまうが、thisでアクセスすれば可能かと思います。

```
var obj = {
    a: 2,
    b: 5,
    c: function(){
        return this.a + this.b;
    }
};
```